# ¿Cómo inhabilitar el uso de la rueda del mouse en un control de tipo NumericUpDown?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, numericupdown, onmousewheel

## Esta pregunta es autorespondida

Recientemente tuve la necesidad de deshabilitar la rueda del mouse en un control NumericUpDown, como es costumbre marque el control y fui al inspector de objetos a buscar algún evento donde pudiera escribir el código de inhabilitación, y resulta que no encontré ningún evento capaz de hacer esto, razón por la cual tuve que buscar otra solución que quiero compartir con la comunidad.

Comment: No es necesario escribir el texto "Esta pregunta es autorespondida". ¿Podrías agregar una imagen de lo que trataste? ¿Que investigaste? ,  te sugerimos revisar [ask].

Comment: @Jorgesys al ser auto-respondida, muy posiblemente la seccion de pregunta tendra el minimo contexto necesario para encajar en el sitio, ya que el grueso de la investigacion y lo que hizo lo demostrara en la respuesta. incluso agregar una imagen puede provocar que no sirva de referencia a usuarios en un futuro con distintas versiones del IDE. saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El **evento MouseWheel** no se muestra por defecto en el **inspector de objetos** pero puede manejarse a través de código:

```
numericupdown1.MouseWheel += (o, ev) => ((HandledMouseEventArgs)ev).Handled = true;
```

Nos suscribimos al **evento MouseWheel**, utilizando un **método anónimo** que recibe dos parámetros y no retorna nada, dentro del cuerpo de este **método anónimo** es que escribimos la instrucción que inhabilita el uso de la rueda del mouse en un **control NumericUpDown**.

Answer (score 2):

En [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) con [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms), deshabilitar la rueda del mouse en un control `NumericUpDown` puede ser un desafío porque no hay un evento directo para manejar esta funcionalidad. Pero mediante la deteccion programatica del evento, podemos controlarlo de la siguiente forma:

Es importante destacar que se puede utilizar la propiedad `Handled` del evento `MouseWheel` del control `NumericUpDown` para evitar que la rueda del mouse tenga efecto.

Tambien hay que tomar en cuenta que debemos suscribirnos al evento `MouseWheel` del control `NumericUpDown`.

```
private void numericUpDown1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
}
```

El código que brinda el usuario Javp en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/612930/315134) es una version más concisa y corta de la que he mostrado yo a esta se le llaman Expresiones Lambda:

```
numericupdown1.MouseWheel += (o, ev) => ((HandledMouseEventArgs)ev).Handled = true;
```

***Pero hay que explicar como esta compuesta:***

- `numericupdown1.MouseWheel`: Esta parte establece la suscripción al evento `MouseWheel` del control `NumericUpDown`. Cuando se detecta un evento de rueda de ratón en el control, se activará el código asociado.
- `+=`: Este operador indica que estamos agregando un nuevo manejador de eventos al evento `MouseWheel`. En este caso, estamos suscribiendo una nueva acción que se ejecutará cuando ocurra el evento.
- `(o, ev) =>`: Esta es una expresión lambda que define un manejador de eventos anónimo. Los parámetros `(o, ev)` representan el objeto que generó el evento (en este caso, el `NumericUpDown`) y los argumentos del evento `MouseWheel`.
- `((HandledMouseEventArgs)ev).Handled = true;`: En esta parte, estamos indicando que queremos manejar el evento de la rueda del ratón para que no tenga ningún efecto. Establecemos la propiedad `Handled` del argumento del evento `MouseWheel` a true, lo que indica que el evento ha sido manejado y no se propaga más allá de este punto.

***Podemos encontrar documentacion oficial relacionada en los siguientes link:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.handledmouseeventargs?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions